# Password management

Tags: passwords, password-management, key-management

I am work in small company. I am Java Developer and Sysadmin of remote servers. I have problem with store password from several servers. How to best way to manage passwords in company?

Comment: The best way to **manage** passwords is... yup, a password **manager**. Google "KeePass", start using it, and never look back.

Comment: It best security? If i want store passwords from database, mq and other infrostucture programms?

Comment: Not, i am not want use externall tools.

Comment: Are you a cryptographer? Do you have any experience with building password managers? If the answer is no you will have to use external tools like keepass because chances are quite large you will screw up when building one yourself, wasting time money and possibly spill your passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your company you want to make sure to use different password databases (KeePass or KeePassX for instance) for each responsible team. You do not want to use a single db if your developers should not have access to prod for instance.

So make a separate db for your prod, QA and dev environments. Next see if you might need to split them up between teams. For instance one for the db team, one for wintel admins,...

If your company keeps growing larger you might need to consider implementing a password escrow service or a system like centrify. This will also increase auditability.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try using [Password Safe](http://passwordsafe.sourceforge.net/).

It creates an encrypted 'safe' that stores all of your passwords and is stored locally.